# Always WWW modrewrite php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I want to force www in my urls. I'm having problems with writing. I know that this code will do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

But I want to put all in $_GET['page']

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

How should I put this together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?page=$0 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `[QSA]`, which allows you to modify the query string of the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```